# Sencha ExtJS store.nextPage() and then store.first() gives the first Record of the previous Page Back

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

```
store.nextPage();
nextId = store.first().get('id');
```

gives the ID of the first Record of the previous page, which should be changed after store.nextPage().

Why, I need the first record of the changed new Page-?

I try this in a custom Controller of Sencha Architect 3

Answer (score 0):

Store loading is asynchronous, you need to wait until the store loads. Look at the store load event.